What are the powers or functions of US electoral college of other than choosing the president?
What are the functions of the US Electoral College other than choosing the president of the United States? If it has no other power does it dissolve immediately after choosing the president?

Did you look at the US Constitution before asking the question?  It's pretty clearly described.

It's also in the first sentence of the EC's Wikipedia page. Is it really less effort to type out a question here than to go to Wikipedia and read the first sentence of the article?

The electoral college has no powers beyond the election of a President:
It's role is completely described in this section of the Constitution

The Electors shall meet in their respective states and vote by ballot for President and Vice-President, one of whom, at least, shall not be an inhabitant of the same state with themselves; they shall name in their ballots the person voted for as President, and in distinct ballots the person voted for as Vice-President, and they shall make distinct lists of all persons voted for as President, and of all persons voted for as Vice-President, and of the number of votes for each, which lists they shall sign and certify, and transmit sealed to the seat of the government of the United States, directed to the President of the Senate.

The lists are then opened in the Senate, and the President and Vice President are chosen by Congress.
Note that the electors never meet as a single body, there are fifty-one such meetings, one per state+DC.  Having sent their list to the seat of government, there is nothing left to do. There's no formal dissolution process, nor is one needed.

There are fifty-one such meetings since the passage of the 23rd amendment.

To nitpick, your 1st sentence is contradicted by the quote.  The other power is election of the Vice-President.  While this is usually a formality in light of the 1st power, a number of questions on the site express curiosity about various hypothetical line of succession anomalies.  So, you may consider being pedantic on this point.

I like James K's answer, above — I even upvoted it — but I want to clarify that the original purpose of the Electoral College was to place an elite deliberative body between the general public and the appointment to the highest office. The founding fathers had a somewhat jaded view of people in masses — like they said in "Men in Black", a 'person' is smart, but 'people' can be dumb, panicky animals — and they wanted a body of cooler, more reflective people monitoring the final decision. Technically speaking, the members of the original Electoral College could have overruled what they saw as a bad or dangerous choice by the general public in their districts, shifting the outcome. They would have had a serious confrontation explaining their reasoning, but their decision would have held.
In essence, the electors were meant to act as a conscience, interceding when the public wanted something that would damage the union as a whole.
The concept was under-thought and poorly implemented from the get-go, and was quickly co-opted by the party system as a tool of political strategy, but it's worth noting what the original intention was so that we can evaluate its current status.

It would have been easy enough to simply make the members of the House and the Senate, sitting in joint session, the Electoral College, in a model similar to the parliamentary system that the Founders were familiar with, that would have been administratively less complicated, and which would have worked in practice much more like it was intended to work. I've never really been clear on why this path wasn't taken.

@ohwilleke: But (1) the House is already tasked with resolving the election if the electoral college fails, and (2) the House is meant to be the populist institution, so one would expect the same intemperate bias in the House as in the general populace. The point of the EC was to serve as a check on an intemperate mass public making irrational choices; it was meant to be filled with people who would put country ahead of party. That's why it has no other function and no permanent powers, to discourage the participation of people who are merely seeking political sway.

@ohwilleke: Note that the Founding Father's original expectation was that the Electoral College would fail to produce a majority winner most of the time, which would have effectively made the EC a qualifying primary for a House election.  They hadn't planned on national political parties forming so quickly.

@dan04 Correct. But why bother with all of the extra political machinery? In most respects, the original U.S. Constitution was minimalist to a fault.

@ohwilleke: the answer to that is checks and balances. The FF tried to spread political power across multiple competitive offices to inhibit the accumulation of power by any single faction. The Presidency was a problem.  They believed they needed a president as a surrogate king-figure who could be electorally 'deposed', but they worried that even the limited powers of the early Presidency might be tempting for factional interests. The EC was meant as a check on the power of factions, and so they wanted to keep that check separate from the faction-prone House. Intentional inefficiency…

The answer by JamesK is fully and completely correct. But it fails to flesh out a rather subtle corollary of the electoral college's powers, in one corner case.
In every Presidential election so far in U.S. history, the Electoral College's electors have had a basically ministerial task: translating the vote of the state voters who elected them into votes for a Presidential and Vice Presidential ticket and transmitting that to Congress.
In a handful of very early elections, the electors had some discretion in the matter. But after that they were pledged to a ticket of candidates and almost always voted accordingly (but perhaps less than 1% of the time voted unfaithfully).
But in the event that the President or Vice President or both, die or are otherwise rendered ineligible or incapable of serving between the Presidential election in which they were elected on the first Tuesday after the first Monday of November (or even earlier if the original candidate's names remained on the ballot), and the date appointed for them to meet at their respective state capitals, the electoral college ends up, in practice, serving as a vacancy committee for the Presidency and Vice Presidency.
In this situation, instead of voting for both persons that they committed to vote for in the electoral college when they were elected as electors, they may instead vote for a substitute person or persons for posts that can no longer be filled by the originally intended candidates.
For example, suppose that President elect Trump and Vice-President elect Vance were on the same airplane prior to the electoral college vote and a freak storm caused it to crash and killed everyone on board. Then, the Republican electors of the electoral college would be charged with voting for someone other than Trump and Vance for President and Vice-President.
In a more absurd example, suppose that today (November 11, 2024), it was disclosed that J.D. Vance was actually born in Scotland to Scottish parents and was then secretly adopted at age seven, and he admitted on national TV with a copy of his original birth certificate displayed, that this was true. Everyone would know at that point that he was not eligible to be elected as Vice President, since he was not a natural born citizen of the United States, and the Trump-Vance electors would probably instead vote for someone recommended by Trump to serve as substitute Vice President elect.
If they all voted for the same substitute ticket, this would be relatively straight forward. But they would not be compelled by any law to do so. If they split their votes for substitute candidates, this could lead to a complex sequence of possible outcomes when their electoral votes were counted in Congress on January 6, 2025, that would depend upon the exact votes for substitute candidates that were cast.

Interesting. Is there any scenario is which, if the Republican electors votes are split, Waltz  or some other Democrat could wind up as the new VP or not?

@Starship There are too many scenarios implicating obscure parts of the U.S. Constitution, to address in a comment.

I need that J.D. Vance conspiracy theory. "Bar-certified attorney suggests that Vance was actually born in Scotland."

@Obie2.0 Ha! A theory I would be stunned by if true.

Trump would almost certainly refute it. We all know that he's the expert on who was or wasn't born in the US.

A similar real-life case to your "absurd example" was 1872 election, in which Presidential candidate Horace Greeley died during the period between Election Day and the Electoral College meetings.  His pledged electors didn't know what to do, so split their vote between multiple candidates.  But given that Greeley's opponent Ulysses S. Grant had won the election anyway, it didn't really matter.

@dan04 If I'd been a wee bit sharper when I wrote this answer, I would have mentioned that excellent example.
